# Can't find Tag info

Tags: git-extensions

I use "Create tag" command in Git Extensions, choose "Create annotated tag" there, type some text as an annotation, tag name for example "Tag01". Later I can see a tag name "Tag01", but can't find the annotation anywhere. It's easy to find an annotation typing "git show Tag01" in command line, but how to do it with Git Extensions UI.

Comment: It's not possible to view annotated tag messages in Git Extensions (at least in current version)

Comment: It's now possible (I'm using 3.00.00.4433).  Annotated tag messages appear in the `Commit` tab, directly under the grey box showing the commit comment.  The format is {underlined tag name}:{annotation}.
Lightweight tags do not appear in this location.
The name of a tag of any type always appears somewhere in the commit details on the `Commit` tab.